# SQl foreign key disabling

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

Is there a way i can declare a disabled foreign key in the table creation in SQL

i don't want to do it by altering the table if possible.

Comment: Just append `DISABLE` at constraint definition. See [constraint_state](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`CONSTRAINT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE), use the `DISABLE` keyword:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  OTHER_ID CONSTRAINT table2__other_id__fk REFERENCES table1 (id) DISABLE
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ta_9s2OF)